# MongovalidatorER Error: User validation failed: password: Path `password` is required, email: Path `email` is required, name: Path `name` is required

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

This is my signup page & I don't get any error with post request with thunderclient but error occurs when using Signup page. I am stuck at this from a long time and I am intermediate in JavaScript. This is my second NextJs program. The users can not sign in to this, if I remove password, user and name's required field it adds an empty entry to mongodb.

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

const Signup = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState()
  const [email, setEmail] = useState()
  const [password, setPassword] = useState()
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if(e.target.name == 'name'){
      setName(e.target.value);
    } 
    else if(e.target.name == 'email'){
      setEmail(e.target.value);
    } 
    else if(e.target.name == 'password'){
      setPassword(e.target.value);
    }
  };
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const data = { name, email, password }
    let res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/signup', {
      method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      
    });
    let response = await res.json();
    console.log(response);
   
    setName('')
    setEmail('')
    setPassword('')
  };

  return (
    <div className="bg-white shadow-md rounded px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4 flex flex-col">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='mt-8 space-y-10' method="POST">
        <div className="mb-4">
          <label
            className="block text-grey-darker text-sm font-bold mb-2"
            htmlFor="name"
          >
            Name
          </label>
          <input
            value={name}
            onChange={handleChange}
            required
            className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-grey-darker"
            id="name"
            type="text"
            placeholder="name"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mb-4">
          <label
            className="block text-grey-darker text-sm font-bold mb-2"
            htmlFor="email"
          >
            Email
          </label>
          <input
            value={email}
            onChange={handleChange}
            required
            className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-grey-darker"
            id="email"
            type="email"
            placeholder="email"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mb-6">
          <label
            className="block text-grey-darker text-sm font-bold mb-2"
            htmlFor="password"
          >
            Password
          </label>
          <input
            value={password}
            onChange={handleChange}
            required
            className="shadow appearance-none border border-red rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-grey-darker mb-3"
            id="password"
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
          />
          <p className="text-red text-xs italic">Please choose a password.</p>
        </div>
        <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
          <button
            className="bg-blue hover:bg-blue-dark text-black font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
            type="submit"
          >
            Sign In
          </button>
          <a
            className="inline-block align-baseline font-bold text-sm text-blue hover:text-blue-darker"
            href={"/forgot"}
          >
            Forgot Password?
          </a>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

 
  );
};
export default Signup;
```

This is my models file

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {type: String, required: true},
        email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
        password: {type: String, required: true},
  
      
    }, {timestamps: true}
);
mongoose.models = {}
// export default mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
export default mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

This is my API

```js
import connectDb from "../../middleware/mongoose"
import User from "../../models/User"
const handler = async (req, res)=> {
    if(req.method == 'POST'){
        let u = new User(req.body)
       await u.save()
    res.status(200).json({success: "success"})
}
    else{
        res.status(400).json({error: "this method is not allowed"})
    }
    
  }
  export default connectDb(handler);
```

This is what I get when I log response

```
{
    properties: [Object],
    kind: 'required',
    path: 'email',
    value: undefined,
    reason: undefined,
    [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
},
```

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log(req.body)` to check if the values are being received ?

Comment: @RyanZeelie Yes, but the values are not being received..